# HTC Desire - phone's dead

Tags: htc-desire, factory-reset, command-line

I was trying my application on HTC Desire when I realized there was a problem with the app so I force stop it. Next thing is the screen freezed - HTC white welcome screen. I tried rebooting several times, but it never got into the desktop. Sometimes it restarted itself. I tried removing the battery as well to no avail. Now my phone is completely dead. I cannot turn it on and when I charge it, the red/green light is not on. What should I do? I was thinking of resetting the phone via command line or something like that. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what your app did, but I find it strange that it is no longer booting. I would suggest trying to get your device in to recovery mode. I have never done this on a non-rooted device so I am not 100% sure you can do a factory reset from the "stock recovery". But I know you can do it on a rooted device.

I found these steps, but again, I am not sure if this pertains to only rooted devices.

1. Turn your desire off, Now hold the volume down and power button in to boot into hboot.
2. Now use the volume button to navigate to boot recovery and select it by pressing the trackpad button.

Comment: No, it does not work. Is it possible that the phone is dead because of the device heat - due to computation? though I am not sure my positioning app will take a lot of resource.

Comment: doubtful, try bringing it back to the carrier, if you can, or even the manufacturer.